# Where can I find the manga for Guilty Crown?

Tags: guilty-crown

I watched *Guilty Crown* over 3 months ago and I still can't get over it, so I decided to read the manga.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find it online. Even when I did, there were only like 1 or 2 chapters.

Is there even a complete manga for *Guilty Crown*? If there is, where I can find it? I don't mind if it's in Japanese.

Comment: Seems the manga is not yet licensed by any English-speaking company, but I'm not really sure. Even so, the Japanese manga (7 volumes) only covers the first 12-episode of the anime.

Comment: Guilty Crown is an original Anime. The Manga and LN are adaptations of that. My personal experience suggests that mostly Anime is more popular as compared to the manga (Anime used to boost Manga sales). So once Anime adaptation, partially finished, is over; people switch to manga. In this case, Guilty Crown had a proper ending, and as such I doubt translations would be a priority. I would suggest rewatching or picking up similar series rather than waiting for Guilty Crown Manga to be translated